# How to show that $\frac{159999}{80000} +\frac{1}{100e^2} <\ln(e^2+\frac{1}{100} ) < 2+ \frac{1}{100e^2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to show that  $\frac{159999}{80000} +\frac{1}{100e^2} < \ln(e^2+\frac{1}{100} ) < 2+ \frac{1}{100e^2}$. I know I should do something with the first order taylor polynomial of $\ln(x)$ around the point $e^2$. but I don't really know how I should tackle this problem.

Comment: @achillehui I do sorry, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job at identifying the first step of this problem.

To help simplify this inequality, use the taylor series for $\ln x$ about $e^2$:

$$\ln x = 2 + \frac{x-e^2}{e^2} - \frac{\left(x-e^2\right)^2}{2e^4} + \frac{\left(x-e^2\right)^3}{3e^6} + \dots$$

Next, note what happens to the first couple of terms when we let $x = e^2 + \frac{1}{100}$:

$$\ln{\left(e^2 + \frac{1}{100}\right)} = 2 + \frac{e^2 + \frac{1}{100} - e^2}{e^2} - \dots = 2 + \frac{1}{100e^2} - \dots$$
Now, note that the first two terms **overapproximate** the true value of $\ln{\left(e^2 + \frac{1}{100}\right)}$, and we can verify that because of the negative sign that follows the next term. Also, the taylor series for $\ln x$ here is a decreasing alternating sequence.

You can also use the alternating series error theorem to show that the maximum error possible when estimating the value of $\ln{\left(e^2 + \frac{1}{100}\right)}$ using the first $2$ terms is the 3rd term.

Can you use these ideas to prove the lower bound of the inequality?

Comment: I think I can, thanks! I wasn't familiar with the alternating series error theorem.

Comment: One could also use the simple transformation $\ln(e^2+1/100)=2+\ln(1+1/(100e^2))$ to get back to the more familiar series for $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4\pm…$.